# Why must I reload instance variables in rspec specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a spec like the following:

```
describe 'toggle_approval' do
  before(:each) do
    @comment = Comment.make(id: 55, approved: false)
  end

  it "toggles the visibility of the discussion" do
    post :toggle_approval, id: 55
    #@comment.reload
    @comment.approved.should be_true
  end
end
```

This spec will fail unless I uncomment the line that reloads the comment. Why is rails not reloading this for me?

Comment: It's simple. Do not use instance variable. Use `let` instead.

Comment: There is no `let` in rspec 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you don't tell it to reload your record. `Comment` instance in your controller is created independently from `@comment` variable set in your specs. So if you don't use `reload` explicitly, it won't be reloaded. If you want your `Comment` instance in controller to be the same instance than in spec, you can do some stubbing:

```
Comment.should_receive(:find).with(@comment.id) { @comment }
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to Marek's answer, you can also call `.reload` inline like so:

```
it "toggles the visibility of the discussion" do
  post :toggle_approval, id: 55
  @comment.reload.approved.should be_true
end
```

or use something like this:

```
it "toggles the visibility of the discussion" do
  expect {
    post :toggle_approval, id: 55
  }.to change {
    @comment.reload.approved
  }.from(...)
   .to(...)
end
```